# How to re-use same fragment across viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `fragment` with a `textView`. I want the `textView` to change when I scroll across the `viewPager`.I want to reuse the same `fragment` rather than creating a new fragment for displaying each `text`.How do I do this? I hope pro developers can understand what I mean.

Comment: Well, don't return a new Fragment, then. Return just one... Or extract some model object to be reused by both Fragments

Comment: Why do you even have a ViewPager if you want the same fragment? Just stay put ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach a same fragment into activity twice simultaneously. If you want the behavior you mentioned don't use `ViewPager`. Just use swipe gesture detection in a layout and maybe some animations.

Comment: Why can't you make the pager adapter return the same instance of the Fragment?

Comment: Because the adapter will also return the same fragment for neighboring pages.